# Build Qt Project in Debug Mode from Command line (aka bash script) in Linux

Tags: linux, qt, bash, makefile, qmake

I already have a project with a .pro file that can be built in debug and release mode. So my question is what is the options on the commandline that I have to specify if I want to build my binaries with debug information. Here is an example building in release using a bash script:

```
cd ${CHECKOUT_DIR_DEV_OGL_DX_ENGINE_SKIA};
echo `date`: "Running \`qmake\` on Skia";
qmake&>${SKIA_LOG};
buildstatus $? "Running \`qmake\` on Skia";
echo `date`: "Running \`make\` on Skia";
make&>${SKIA_LOG};
buildstatus $? "Running \`make\` on Skia Please see ${SKIA_LOG}";
```

What do I need to add to get it now to also build in debug mode?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The option you need is "CONFIG+=debug". See [General Configuration](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html#general-configuration) in [qmake Manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html).

```
#!/bin/bash
qmake CONFIG+=debug ${qmake_options}
make ${make_options}
```

Comment: I thought that was only to be used in the project file. I have CONFIG+=debug_and_release, which allows me to build both using QtCreator. However since my build process is automated I can't use QtCreator. Do you know if passing this on the command line will build in debug mode?